# Pyinstaller Qt5 Application won't start in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, qt5, pyinstaller, pyside2

I have created a Python program with Qt5 GUI and compiled an .exe with PyInstaller. It works fine on most PCs, but on some the compiled .exe wont start at all. No error message, no process in taskmanager, no entry in system protocol. I uninstalled anti virus program and disabled windows defender, still the same. The funny thing is, that when I open a command prompt and start the .exe from within the command prompt it works as it should. But it does not when double clicking the .exe from within windows explorer. The Windows OS is Windows 10.

Any suggestions or somebody had same/similar issue?

Regards
David

EDIT: Windows UAC was the problem: when turend completely off the application does not start.

Comment: Hi Try to run your exe from a command prompt, you will get error traceback is any error occurs.

Comment: Most of the time issue occurs because of some missing DLL file in system.

Comment: Hi, i figured it out meanwhile: when running from command prompt it did run with no error. It was UAC from Windows - when turend completly off the application doesn't start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows UAC was the problem: when turend completely off the application does not start.